# Logarithms and exponential

Tags: logarithms

A Straight line is added to y=ln(2x+7) to obtain a solution of e^4x(2x+7)-e^9=0. Determine the equation of the straight line. Please help

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Finding the asymptote of y=ln(2x+y). X=-3

Comment: I can’t seem to solve the second equation. Are we supposed to?

Comment: Please help..I can’t understand

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{4x}(2x+7)=e^9 \ \iff \ e^{4x-9}(2x+7)=1$$

Take the natural logarithm of LHS and RHS :

$$(4x-9)+\text{ln}(2x+7)=0$$

Is $y=4x-9$ what you call the "straight line" to be added ?

Comment: Thanks so this is the solution?

Comment: The way you have asked the question, this "looks" to be the solution...

Comment: Besides, I have had a look at questions you have asked in the past : please chek answers that are satisfying for you. Doing that helps future readers to know that a certain answer is the good one.